# How to prevent controls are added into a component derived from TCustomPanel?

Tags: delphi, components

I've defined a component derived from `TCustomPanel` but sometimes I accidentally add some other controls inside of it.

**Run-time:**

```
  TMyPanel = class(TCustomPanel)
  public
    //...
  end;
```

**Design-time:**

```
procedure Register();
begin
  RegisterCustomModule(TCustomPanel, TCustomModule);
  RegisterComponents('MyTestComponents', [
    TMyPanel
  ]);
end;
```

I don't want that who install and uses my component can accidentally add other controls inside of it.
How to prevent controls are added to the component when it's *direct child* of a Form/Frame?

**Steps to reproduce the behavior:**

1. Create a new form
2. Add a `TMyPanel`
3. While the `TMyPanel` is selected, add another control

The new control will be added inside the panel.

Comment: TPanel is a container, so this is expected behaviour. What do you want your panel to do under these circumstances? Are you saying that you will *never* want to add a subcomponent at design time or run time?

Comment: @Dsm: While designing the panel itself I want to be able to place other controls inside the panel . But I don't want that other controls can be placed inside the panel when using the panel as a component in a form/frame..

Comment: @ExDev: that doesn't really make sense. The panel will *always* be inside a Form/Frame at design-time.  Unless you mean you want to ignore controls when the panel is a *direct* child of the Form/Frame but you want it to accept controls when it is child of another control.  If that is the case, then you can either 1) override the `SetParent()` method and toggle the `csAcceptsControls` flag in the `ControlStyle` property based on the type of `Parent` being assigned, or 2) override the `ValidateInsert()` method and throw an exception if the current `Parent` is a Form/Frame.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Yes, I didn't know the words for properly explain this, I've updated the question, it should be clearer now. Anyhow, removing csAcceptsControls is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the simplest way (which can be overridden) is to set the controlStyle element in its constructor, like this

```
interface

uses
  VCL.ExtCtrls,
  VCL.Controls,
  System.Classes;

type
TMyPanel = class(TCustomPanel)
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

implementation

{ TMyPanel }

constructor TMyPanel.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  // ...
  ControlStyle := ControlStyle - [ csAcceptsControls ];
end;
```

If you wanted to be able to change this behaviour at design time, you would also publish the ControlStyle property.